# Problems regarding paragraphs and indentation in a WPF flowdocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I am having some trouble with flow document. Would like to create multiple paragraphs with a figure at the start surrounded by text. But I don't want any indentation. The funny thing is that the figure is not indented if I have enough text.

Heres some code to put right into kaxaml which illustrates the problem.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <BitmapImage x:Key="notasingle" UriSource="http://knowyourmeme.com/i/000/069/709/original/1283530186379.png?1283530926"/>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
      </Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Figure}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAnchor" Value="PageLeft"/>
      </Style>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Width="350">
         <FlowDocument>
            <Section>
               <Paragraph>
                  <Figure>
                     <Paragraph>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource notasingle}"/>
                     </Paragraph>
                  </Figure>   
                  Some text askdfjlø ajsdføj øajsdfj aøsldkfj akløsdfj øalksjdføl jaøsdfj aløsdfjlø ajksdføl jasdløfj aasdjføklj asdkløfdjalsjkdfløakjs df
               </Paragraph>
               <Paragraph>
                  <Figure>
                     <Paragraph>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource notasingle}"/>
                     </Paragraph>
                  </Figure>
               </Paragraph>
               <Paragraph>
                  <Figure>
                     <Paragraph>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource notasingle}"/>
                     </Paragraph>
                  </Figure>
               </Paragraph>
               <Paragraph>
                  <Figure>
                     <Paragraph>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource notasingle}"/>
                     </Paragraph>
                  </Figure>
               </Paragraph>
               <Paragraph>
                  <Figure>
                     <Paragraph>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource notasingle}"/>
                     </Paragraph>
                  </Figure>
               </Paragraph>
            </Section>
         </FlowDocument>
      </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```